# Thunderbird filter problem

Tags: thunderbird

I keep getting spammed to go to a *.*.ru url. I've tried every combination of filters I can think of like body contains *.ru, body contains .ru, but nothing works. Is it a bug that I can't select a portion of a word to use as a filter? The spam url's are always different so I can't provide a specific url. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why filter on the body and not the incoming address?